# Does there exists $f\in \mathcal{S} (\mathbb R)$ so $\hat{f}=1$ on a comapct set $C$ and $\hat{f}=0$ outside $C\subset W$ (open set)?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

Let $C$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R,$ $V\subset \mathbb R,$ and $0<m(V)<\infty,$ where $m$ is a Lebsgue measure on $\mathbb R.$

**My Question is**: Can we expect to find $k\in \mathcal{S(\mathbb R)}$ (=[Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space)) such that (a) $\hat{k}(x)=1$ for all $x \in C,$ $\hat{k}(x)=0,$ outside  $C+V\setminus V,$ and $0\leq \hat{k}(x)\leq 1, $ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$ (b)What can we say about $\|k\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}$ ?

**Motivation**:

**Fact**. Let $C$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R,$ $V\subset \mathbb R,$ and $0<m(V)<\infty,$ where $m$ is a Lebsgue measure on $\mathbb R.$ Then there exists $k\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ such that (a) $\hat{k}(x)=1$ for all $x \in C,$ $\hat{k}(x)=0,$ outside  $C+V\setminus V,$ and $0\leq \hat{k}(x)\leq 1, $ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$ (b) $\|k\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}\leq \{m(C\setminus V)/m(V)\}^{\frac{1}{2}}.$

**Proof.** Let $g$ and $h$ be the functions in $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ whose Plancherel Fourier transforms are the characteristic functions of $V$ and $C\setminus V$ respectively, and define
$$k(y):=\frac{g(y) h(y)}{m(v)}, (y\in \mathbb R).$$
Then $\hat{k}= m(V)^{-1} (\hat{g}\ast \hat{h}),$ or
$\hat{k}(x)=\frac{1}{m(V)} \int_{V} \hat{h}(x-y) dy, (x\in \mathbb R).$ If $x\in C, $ then $\hat{h}(x-y)=1, $ for all $y\in V,$ hence $\hat{k}(x)= 1.$ If $x\notin C+V\setminus V,$ then 
$\hat{h}(x-y)=0$ for all $y\in V.$ This proves (a); and (b) follows from Schwartz inequality.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform ${\cal S}(\mathbb{R})\to {\cal S}(\mathbb{R})$ is a linear isometry (Fourier inversion). If $C\subseteq W$ where $C$ is compact and $W$ is open, then we can find a smooth function $g$ such that $g\equiv 1$ on $C$ and $g\equiv 0$ outside $W$ (why?). Let us take $W=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: d(x,C)<1\}$ for concreteness and observe now that $g$ is evidently Schwartz. Therefore, there exists $f\in {\cal S}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\widehat{f}=g$ (you can take $f(x)=\widehat{g}(-x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$; again this is simply Fourier inversion).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, if you want to allow $W$ to be arbitrary, then simply note that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: d(x,C)<\epsilon\}\subseteq W$ for *any open* $W\supseteq C$ and you can apply the reasoning above with "$\{x\in\mathbb{R}:d(x,C)<\epsilon\}$" in place of "$W$".

Comment: @AD, thanks; What can we say about $\|f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)} ?$ (Of course,Since $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$, we have, $\|f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}< \infty,$, but can we expect bit more ?)

Comment: Hi @Divyang, it might be easy to answer this question but I don't think I will contemplate it right now in too much detail (but I will try to do so later on). However, I will quickly post one observation: by the boundedness of the Fourier transform operator (which, in fact, has norm $1$), we know that $\left\|f\right|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}\leq 1$ (since $\widehat{f}$ is bounded in $L^{\infty}$ norm by $1$). (You might have already observed this.) That's what immediately comes to my mind but there might be other avenues of obtaining better bounds which I will think about ...

Comment: ... in the meantime, please let me know if you think of anything yourself; I think this is an interesting problem!

Comment: Hi @DivyangBhimani, sorry, I think it should be $\left\|f\right|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}\geq 1$ in my second comment above - I got the direction of the inequality estimate incorrect! Sorry! I think this is still useful to know though, a lower bound on $\left\|f\right\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}$, but I do wonder whether we could obtain a nice upper bound as well.